# What is the best versioning way by a project

Tags: project, versioning, version-numbering

It is very confusing with versioning. I saw lots of versioning samples. Some of them contains even subversion information. Many of them looks ok.

- 0.5
- 0.1.0
- 0.0.1.0
- 5.5.5.2_R139
- ...

What is the best practise/best way for software-versioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather a topic for the [**programmers**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) IMHO. You may want to take a look at [**this post**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77206/what-is-your-application-versioning-strategy/77208#77208), where several approaches are discussed.